Quiescence search doesn't work as expected
I have been working on developing a chess engine using C#. It usually works fine, but in some specific positions, like after 1.d4 d5 c4, the quiescence search throws an error.
I'm using two things to represent a board. One is a 64-length int array, which stores every square's piece. The other is an int list, which stores every piece's location.
For example, in K7/8/8/8/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1
in this position, the first one will be like [(king value), 0, 0, ......0] and the second one will be {0}.
I found out that the error occurs because those two values don't match during the quiescence search. the second list, where you store the position of the pieces, says that there is one more piece while the first array doesn't agree.
These are the codes for the quiescence search. I divided them into two like a minimax search.
in this code, you can find out that there are unnecessary array copy codes. This is because I tested if it's about memory location issue.
when I call quiescence search on Min part
 int Val;
                bool isComplete;
                int[] Copy = new int[64];
                Array.Copy(CB, Copy, CB.Length);
                (Val, isComplete) = quiescenceMin(Q_DEPTH, Copy, HashList, WKC, WQC, BKC, BQC, lMove, int.MinValue, int.MaxValue, Hash);

on Max part
                int Val;
                bool isComplete;
                int[] Copy = new int[64];
                Array.Copy(CB, Copy, CB.Length);
                (Val, isComplete) = quiescenceMax(Q_DEPTH, Copy, HashList, WKC, WQC, BKC, BQC, lMove,int.MinValue, int.MaxValue, Hash);

(int, bool) quiescenceMax(int depth, int[] CB, List<int> HashList, bool WKC, bool WQC, bool BKC, bool BQC, Move lMove, int alpha, int beta, UInt64 h)
    {
        

        int[] Board = new int[64];
        List<int> HL = new(HashList);
        List<Move> MoveList = new();
        bool Check;
        bool isCheckingMove;
        int Col = Piece.White;

        Array.Copy(CB, Board, 64);


        UInt64 Hash = h;


        int eval = EvaluateBoard(Board, HashList, WKC, WQC, BKC, BQC);


        if (depth == 0)
        {
            return (eval, true);
        }
        if (eval >= beta)
        {
            return (beta, true);
        }
        if(eval > alpha)
        {
            alpha = eval;
        }
        (MoveList, Check ,isCheckingMove) = GenerateLegalMoves(WKC, WQC, BKC, BQC, CB, HashList, Col, false, true);
        if (MoveList.Count == 0)
        {
            if (Check)
            {
                return (-100000000, true);
            }
            else
            {
                return (0, true);
            }

        }


        bool WhiteKingCastle = WKC;
        bool WhiteQueenCastle = WQC;
        bool BlackKingCastle = BKC;
        bool BlackQueenCastle = BQC;
        if (depth != 1)
        {
            MoveList.Sort(CompareMoves);
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < MoveList.Count; i++)
        {
            WhiteKingCastle = WKC;
            WhiteQueenCastle = WQC;
            BlackKingCastle = BKC;
            BlackQueenCastle = BQC;

            Hash = h;

            if (TimeControl.ElapsedMilliseconds >= TIME_LIMIT)
            {
                return (0, false);
            }
            if (!IsCapture(MoveList[i])) continue; // skips if it's not capture move
            QmoveCount++;
            (Board, HL) = MakeMove(MoveList[i], CB, HashList, ref Hash);
            if (WKC && ((Board[60] != (Piece.White | Piece.King)) || (Board[63] != (Piece.White | Piece.Rook))))
            {
                WhiteKingCastle = false;
            }
            if (WQC && ((Board[60] != (Piece.White | Piece.King)) || (Board[56] != (Piece.White | Piece.Rook))))
            {
                WhiteQueenCastle = false;
            }


            (int Score, bool isReal) = quiescenceMin(depth - 1, Board, HL, WhiteKingCastle, WhiteQueenCastle, BlackKingCastle, BlackQueenCastle, MoveList[i], alpha, beta, Hash);
            if (!isReal)
            {
                return (0, false);
            }
            
            if (Score >= beta)
            {
                return (beta, true);
            }
            if (Score > alpha)
            {
                alpha = Score;
                
            }
        }
        return (alpha, true);
        int CompareMoves(Move move1, Move move2)
        {

            if (move1.To == lMove.To)
            {
                if (move2.To == lMove.To)
                    return 0; // Both moves capture the lastly moved piece.
                else
                    return -1; // move1 captures the lastly moved piece.
            }
            else if (move2.To == lMove.To)
            {
                return 1; // move2 captures the lastly moved piece.
            }
            if (IsCapture(move1) && IsCapture(move2))
            {
                //Debug.Log(move1.From + ", " + move1.To + "," + move1.Type);
                //Debug.Log(move2.From + ", " + move2.To + "," + move2.Type);
                int value1 = Get_MVVLVA_Value(move1, CB);
                int value2 = Get_MVVLVA_Value(move2, CB);
                return value2.CompareTo(value1); // Sort in descending order
            }
            else if (IsCapture(move1))
            {
                return -1; // move1 is a capture, move2 is not
            }
            else if (IsCapture(move2))
            {
                return 1; // move2 is a capture, move1 is not
            }
            else
            {
                return 0; // Both moves are non-captures; maintain their order
            }
        }
    }

(int, bool) quiescenceMin(int depth, int[] CB, List<int> HashList, bool WKC, bool WQC, bool BKC, bool BQC, Move lMove, int alpha, int beta, UInt64 h)
    {
        int[] Board = new int[64];

        
        List<int> HL = new(HashList);
        List<Move> MoveList = new();
        bool Check;
        bool isCheckingMove;
        int Col = Piece.Black;
        UInt64 Hash = h;
        Array.Copy(CB, Board, 64);
        int eval = EvaluateBoard(Board, HL, WKC, WQC, BKC, BQC);
        if (depth == 0)
        {
            return (eval, true);
        }
        if (eval < alpha)
        {
            return (alpha, true);
        }
        if (eval < beta)
        {
            beta = eval;
        }
        (MoveList, Check, isCheckingMove) = GenerateLegalMoves(WKC, WQC, BKC, BQC, CB, HashList, Col, false, true);
        if (MoveList.Count == 0)
        {
            if (Check)
            {
                return (100000000, true);
            }
            else
            {
                return (0, true);
            }

        }


        bool WhiteKingCastle = WKC;
        bool WhiteQueenCastle = WQC;
        bool BlackKingCastle = BKC;
        bool BlackQueenCastle = BQC;
        if (depth != 1)
        {
            MoveList.Sort(CompareMoves);
        }
        //Move BestMove = new Move(0, 0, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < MoveList.Count; i++)
        {
            WhiteKingCastle = WKC;
            WhiteQueenCastle = WQC;
            BlackKingCastle = BKC;
            BlackQueenCastle = BQC;
            Hash = h;
            if (TimeControl.ElapsedMilliseconds >= TIME_LIMIT)
            {
                return (0, false);
            }
            if (!IsCapture(MoveList[i])) continue; // skips if it's not capture move
            QmoveCount++;
            (Board, HL) = MakeMove(MoveList[i], CB, HashList, ref Hash);
            if (BKC && (Board[4] != (Piece.Black | Piece.King)) || (Board[7] != (Piece.Black | Piece.Rook)))
            {
                BlackKingCastle = false;

            }

            if (BQC && (Board[4] != (Piece.Black | Piece.King)) || (Board[0] != (Piece.Black | Piece.Rook)))
            {
                BlackQueenCastle = false;
            }

            (int Score, bool isReal) = quiescenceMax(depth - 1, Board, HL, WhiteKingCastle, WhiteQueenCastle, BlackKingCastle, BlackQueenCastle, MoveList[i], alpha, beta, Hash);
            if(!isReal)
            {
                return (0, false);
            }
            if (Score <= alpha)
            {
                return (alpha, true);
            }
            if (Score < beta)
            {
                beta = Score;
                
            }
        }
        return (beta, true);
        int CompareMoves(Move move1, Move move2)
        {

            if (move1.To == lMove.To)
            {
                if (move2.To == lMove.To)
                    return 0; // Both moves capture the lastly moved piece.
                else
                    return -1; // move1 captures the lastly moved piece.
            }
            else if (move2.To == lMove.To)
            {
                return 1; // move2 captures the lastly moved piece.
            }
            if (IsCapture(move1) && IsCapture(move2))
            {

                int value1 = Get_MVVLVA_Value(move1, CB);
                int value2 = Get_MVVLVA_Value(move2, CB);
                return value2.CompareTo(value1); // Sort in descending order
            }
            else if (IsCapture(move1))
            {
                return -1; // move1 is a capture, move2 is not
            }
            else if (IsCapture(move2))
            {
                return 1; // move2 is a capture, move1 is not
            }
            else
            {
                return 0; // Both moves are non-captures; maintain their order
            }
        }
    }

KeyNotFoundException: The given key '0' was not present in the dictionary.
The error occurs in the Evaluate function, where you are trying to access the dictionary with the piece on specific location.
I can post other codes if you need, and will answer other questions too.
thanks!
I tried copying the array value to check if it's memory location issue, but the same error occured.

Having two different board representations that can get out of step like this is problematic. Have you checked them by hand to see which one is correct? You can probably trim out all the irrelevant pieces and pawns for testing (ie. make start position /4K3/2PP4/8/8/8/8/3p4/4k3/ to test it out). BTW it is more common to do make a move and unmake a move and just have one current active board and a list of moves at each ply. Copying the entire board at each ply is an unnecessary overhead.
